# How do you terminate a process inside a shell in emacs?

Tags: shell, emacs, terminate

I work a lot in a shell inside emacs (on a Mac). It used to be that, when I typed control-Q control-C, that would kill a process running in the shell. About a year ago, though, that stopped working for some reason; now it has no effect. Anyone know why, or another way of doing this?

Comment: see the comint-mode-map (`C-h m` from shell), there are a number of commands to send signals, but `C-c C-c` (`comint-interrupt-subjob`)  should usually work? If a process isn't responding to normal interruption, the elisp functions, `kill-process` and `interrupt-process` are less forgiving

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately C-c C-c does not work (that's control-c twice, right?) When I type it, I just see "C-c C-c" appearing on the screen. As for "kill-process", I don't know how to run this command. "M-x kill-process" does not work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: kill-process isn't an interactive function. If C-c C-c not working, you can kill the process from M-x process-list, followed by a d on the specific process - `M-x proced` followed by marking processes gives you more control over sending specific signals to sub-processes as well

Comment: I think you mean `M-x list-processes`? (`M-x process-list` doesn't seem to exist.) This does not show my process. (My process is just a 3-line perl script with an endless loop.) Also ps does not show my process. If I do ps -e, I see it, and then I can kill it. This makes me think that the process is being associated with a different user (the user is listed as ??) but I don't know how to change that. Thank you again, this help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: as mentioned before, `proced` will list subprocesses.

Comment: I found a solution: using M-x eshell instead of M-x shell. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using `term-mode`.

I bound `term-interrupt-subjob` to my keybinding of choice with:

```lisp
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
                (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-'") 'term-interrupt-subjob)
```

I am not sure which mode you are using to interact with a shell from Emacs (the inferior shell, Emacs shell, or the terminal emulator). So you might have to modify this a little by replacing `term-interrupt-subjob` by, for instance, `comint-interrupt-subjob` and changing the mode hook.

---

*To answer your questions in the comments:*

- You add the function in your .emacs file. For it to take effect, you need to evaluate it: you can select it and run `M-x eval-region` or you can restart Emacs.
- If you are running `M-x shell`, you are using `shell-mode`. 
  Note that to know which major mode you are using, you can run [describe-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Help.html).
- Since you are using `shell-mode`, you want to use `add-hook 'shell-mode-hook` instead of `add-hook 'term-mode-hook` and `shell-mode-map` instead of `term-raw-map`.

However, in `shell-mode`, C-c C-c does by default run the command `comint-interrupt-subjob`. So this should work out of the box as Rorschach said. I am not sure why it isn't working for you.

You can try:

```lisp
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook (lambda ()
                (define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'comint-interrupt-subjob)
```

to see if that helps. But this should already be set since it is the default, so it is really unclear whether it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm not sure where to put the `add-hook...` command - in .emacs, or in .bash_profile? (Neither one seems to work.) To respond to your second point, I'm not sure which "mode" I'm using either. I simply open a terminal window on the Mac and type "emacs", and then I do `M-x shell`. Thank you again!

Comment: I found a solution: Using M-x eshell instead of M-x shell. Thank you for your help!